# Get nearby places with mongoDB and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a small database with places I have added manually and I'm trying to filter them by minDistance and maxDistance.

So this is the mongoose schema

```
 var schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: [Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
        index: '2dsphere',     // create the geospatial index
        required: false // true senare
    }
});
```

this is the method used to get the nearby places:

```
schema.statics.getNearby = function (longitude, latitude, minDistance, maxDistance, callback) {

    if ((longitude || latitude) === undefined) return new ModelError("location or radius is missing");

    var Places = this;
    var point = { type: "Point", coordinates: [ longitude, latitude]};
    Places.geoNear(point, { minDistance: minDistance, maxDistance : maxDistance},
        function(err, activities, stats) {
            if (err)  return callback(err);
            callback(null, activities);
    });
};
```

And this is the error code i get when executing this method:

```
  500 Error
   at Error.MongoError (/home/ec2-user/bored_server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:13:17)
   at Function.MongoError.create (/home/ec2-user/bored_server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
   at /home/ec2-user/bored_server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:768:66
   at Callbacks.emit (/home/ec2-user/bored_server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:84:3)
   at null.messageHandler (/home/ec2-user/bored_server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:218:23)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/bored_server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:259:22)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
   at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
```

The thing that bugs me is that with mongodb i can do a query like this and it works fine.

```
db.places.find({ 
    location: { 
        $nearSphere : { 
            $geometry: { 
                type: "Point",  
                coordinates: [ 18, 58] }, 
                $minDistance: 0, 
                $maxDistance: 1000000 
                } 
            } 
        }
    )
```

Edit1:
His solution was that he should specify the maxDistance value in meters, i cannot see how that would help me since i just get an error no matter what value i specify as maxdistance. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose calls to geoNear with GeoJSON points as query parameters not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623998/mongoose-calls-to-geonear-with-geojson-points-as-query-parameters-not-working)

Comment: I didnt find that helpful, doesnt solve my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, minDistance and maxDistance was string type, for maxDistance that works fine, but for minDistance i hade to convert it to float or int.
A dirty solution would be this code:

```
schema.statics.getNearby = function (longitude, latitude, minDistance, maxDistance, callback) {

if ((longitude || latitude) === undefined) return new ModelError("location or radius is missing");

var Places = this;
var point = { type: "Point", coordinates: [ longitude, latitude]};
Places.geoNear(point, { minDistance: parseFloat(minDistance), maxDistance : maxDistance},
    function(err, activities, stats) {
        if (err)  return callback(err);
        callback(null, activities);
});
```

};

Now this would only be neccessary if minDistance is string type.
Thanks.